# Perl wrong UTF-8 output

Tags: perl, encoding, utf-8

I have the following program:

```perl
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;

print "\x{00a0}\n";
```

When I run it, it produces the wrong UTF-8 encoding:

```
$ ./nbsp.pl | od -tx1
0000000 a0 0a
0000002
```

My expectation would be this:

```
$ printf '\u00a0\n' | od -tx1
0000000 c2 a0 0a
0000003
```

Why is [`00a0`](https://www.compart.com/de/unicode/U+00A0) encoded as `a0` instead of `c2a0` as it should be?

The same happens, when I try to parse JSON data:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON::Parse qw(parse_json);

my $json = parse_json ('{"nbsp":"\u00A0"}');
print $json->{nbsp}, "\n";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't need the `utf8` pragma but a statement to encode output. Best use [open pragma](https://perldoc.perl.org/open)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use open ":std", ":encoding(UTF-8)";

print "\x{00a0}\n";
```

Comment: But my locale is already set to UTF-8. Why do I have to tell Perl twice? And how about a system not using UTF-8? If I force UTF-8, the script will not work anymore on such a system.

Comment: @ceving Perl doesn't look at locale to determine a default encoding unless you tell it to via [`use open ':locale';`](https://perldoc.perl.org/open) or whatever.

Comment: The `-C` switch to `perl` is also useful for setting up default encodings on the standard filehandles.

Comment: I like `use utf8::all;`, which sets the filehandles and all manner of other utf8 stuff that I often forget otherwise.